# Start a system service in the Postgres docker container

Tags: linux, bash, postgresql, docker, cron

I want to extends the `postgres:10.2` Dockerfile in order to add a cron job doing some SQL queries at specific dates:

```
FROM postgres:10.2

COPY task-purge.sh /usr/local/share/
RUN chown postgres:postgres /usr/local/share/task-purge.sh
RUN chmod 700 /usr/local/share/task-purge.sh

COPY query-task-purge.sql /usr/local/share/
RUN chown postgres:postgres /usr/local/share/query-task-purge.sql
RUN chmod 700 /usr/local/share/query-task-purge.sql
```

The problem is: the cron service is not started:

Inside the docker container:

```
root@5c17ce88c333:/# service cron status
[FAIL] cron is not running ... failed!
root@5c17ce88c333:/# pgrep cron
root@5c17ce88c333:/#
```

I have difficulties to start it ...

In the Dockerfile, I tried :

- To add `RUN service cron start`: nothing change
- To add `CMD service cron start`: when the container starts, it ends with `Starting periodic command scheduler: cron` without starting the DB.
- To add `CMD postgres && service cron start`: when the container starts, it ends with `"root" execution of the PostgreSQL server is not permitted.` without starting the DB.
- To add a wrappere CMD script like https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/: same behaviour.
- To add `ENTRYPOINT "docker-entrypoint.sh" && service cron start`: idem
- To add `service cron start` in a new `docker-entrypoint.sh` (modified from the official postgres:10.2 Dockerfile https://hub.docker.com/layers/postgres/library/postgres/10.2/images/sha256-4b6b7bd361a3b7b69531b2c16766a38b0f3a89e9243f5a49ff16180dd2d42273?context=explore): `Starting periodic command scheduler: croncron: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied failed!`
- To add `update-rc.d cron defaults && update-rc.d cron enable` to the `docker-entrypoint.sh`: nothing change.
- To add `set -- su-exec root:root /bin/bash -c "service cron start"`: nothing change
- To add `set -- su-exec root:root /bin/bash -c "update-rc.d cron defaults && update-rc.d cron enable"`: nothing change
- To add `gosu root:root /bin/bash -c "service cron start"`: the container ends with `error: failed switching to "root:root": operation not permitted.`
- To add `exec gosu root:root /bin/bash -c "service cron start"`: the container ends with `Starting periodic command scheduler: cron.`

Do you have any idea how I can run a system service before postgres start ? And I want to extends postgres:10.2.

Thanks !

Comment: A container runs a single process; it doesn't run "services" or init scripts, and often commands like `service` will fail either silently or with an opaque error.  You can run your cron job from a separate container or from the host.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have understand why ... I answer my own question to help everybody : the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script runs a `exec gosu postgres "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"` command (even in the last postgres version: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh) which call again this script but as `postgres` user.

So every system operations needs to be executed before this command.

For example: write a function called `system_configure` and call it before that line:

```sh
# ... (outside main)
system_configure() {
    echo "[x] Crontab service start ..."
    service cron start
    echo "[x] Crontab service started"
}

# ... (inside main function path)
    system_configure

    exec gosu postgres "$BASH_SOURCE" "$@"

# ... (end main)
```

You could also use any other docker image like ubuntu with supervisord, but prefers distroless image for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Just run it once in your `Dockerfile` using:

`RUN service cron start`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).